# Bootstrap on Ios browser - border and text in html

Tags: html, ios, css

I have problem with my code on iphone browser. My problem is that the text disappears and div border or shadow is different only on iphone browser. I also test the web on safari browser and it's look good. Actually the developer version on this website is run on: [Contact](http://pomyslownia.twsoft.pl/kontakt/).

As you see form have other type shadow or border in form and the phone number is hidden only on ios browser. Why is there such a difference and how can you deal with such a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code for mobile devices (i checked on iPhone 6S)

```
<h3 class="contact-number"> Tel: <a href="tel:606 885 666; 501">606 885 666; 501</a> 644 924 </h3>
```

by default the `a` tag has `color:#fff;`, changing the color code to any other color and it fixes it.

example:

```
  <h3 class="contact-number"> Tel: <a href="tel:606 885 666; 501" style="color:red;">606 885 666; 501</a> 644 924 </h3>
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it, but do you know why the shadow or border in form input view different in ios ?

Comment: Try this  `input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], textarea{background-clip: padding-box;
} `